# OCaml difference between 'a option list and 'a list

Tags: types, ocaml

I got the following results when typing this function into the OCaml toplevel.  The input appears to be identical to me both times, other that the whitespace surrounding the `::` operator.  Can anyone explain the difference between `'a option list` and `'a option` here?

```
# let rec at i = function
  | [] -> None
  | h::t -> if i = 1 then Some h else at (i-1) t;;
    val at : int -> 'a option list -> 'a option = <fun>
# let rec at i = function
  | [] -> None
  | h :: t -> if i = 1 then Some h else at (i-1) t;;
    val at : int -> 'a list -> 'a option = <fun>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I see:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let rec at i = function
  | [] -> None
  | h::t -> if i = 1 then Some h else at (i-1) t;;
val at : int -> 'a list -> 'a option = <fun>
# let rec at i = function
  | [] -> None
  | h :: t -> if i = 1 then Some h else at (i-1) t;;
val at : int -> 'a list -> 'a option = <fun>
```

In my opinion, your experiment was flawed in some way. The spacing around `::` isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: You must be right.  I couldn't recreate the problem, so it must have been related to some previous let binding that I had forgotten about.  Thanks!